# How to get a list of images in a a prticular folder?

Tags: linux

My folder contains  5 -6 images, I want to  display a list of the names of all images only. However the folder contains two text files.

Comment: what are the names of your image files? Do they all have the same extension, or the same type? If they are not can the text files be identified (so you can filter them out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do this from the command line?

If so, use ls

```
ls *.jpg
```

`*` is a wildcard

which will get all files that end with .jpg